# Maintain HTTP session after login

Tags: c#

I'm able to login successfully, but after login, I can't seem to successfully call other method.  I searched online that i need to keep HTTP session between calls, but I have done that and still not working.  Can you please take a look at the sample code below and see what else is missing?  Thanks.

EndPoint: http://"my domain"/account/login

Method: GET

Parameters: username, password

I cannot seem to call successfully when requesting URL below after login successfully above URL:

EndPoint: http://"my domain"/Api/games

Parmaters: none

```
    public string MakeRequest(string parameters)
    {
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        string URL = EndPoint + parameters;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

        request.CookieContainer = cookie;

        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // grab the response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            return responseValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "HTTP session"?

Comment: just trying to maintain the session over HTTP on the client.

Comment: The web is stateless, so I don't know what you mean by "maintain the session over HTTP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the same cookie container between calls.

Modify your method to allow the caller to inject the container:

```
public string MakeRequest(string parameters, CookieContainer cookie)
```

then call it like this:

```
var cookie = new CookieContainer();
MakeRequest(loginUrl, cookie);
MakeRequest(urlThatRequiresSession, cookie);
```

Or, you could just scope `cookie` at the instance level instead of local.

Comment: Most servers will only allow one connection from a client PC per user.  The server uses the cookies to determine the number of connections.  So make sure you are using the same cookies like John said.  It may help to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to determine why the connection is actually closing and what errors are occurring.

Comment: that would explain why because I keep creating new cookie for every request.  Thanks.

Comment: John Wu, after following your suggestion and fixing my other code bugs, I now can make second request successfully after login.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: jdweng, Thanks for the suggested tools.  i definitely check them out now to learn more of what's going on with this quick expired connection.